# Curl Post take lot of time

Tags: php, yii

On my server there is one url n.php, that have below code.

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $Url,
            CURLOPT_POST => 1,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postParams,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
));
$curlResponse = curl_exec($curl);
```

n.php takes get values and post it to yii Service on the same server. yii service is only saving data to db.

But it takes lot of time to post data through curl.
Any solution to reduce this processing time.

Comment: `it takes lot of time` => I am assuming you get a response at last. In that case, it's not cURL that needs fixing but rather your yii service. What is the data that gets posted? Is it too large?

Comment: no data is not large...only 10 fields with max 50 chars in data

Comment: Ok, can you show your Yii service code? It's difficult to debug without much context because the bottleneck could be anywhere.

Comment: Have you tried to make a request to your service by tools like Postman and debug the service script?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your cURL, maybe the problem is the yii service,  but i doubt it, probably the DB is slow.

Like the comments say debug the service, i have a feeling that is the DB that make this request slow, make a return with before the db save (don't save) and if still slow keep debuging untill you find the part that is slowing down this request.